# Can I send data in header with a link

Tags: php, laravel, curl, http-headers

I am using laravel. I am sending email using amazon ses. In the email I am sending a link, With that link I want to pass some data in the header, so that when user will open that link, i can verify the token and want to authenticate user. (I don't want to pass the token in url).

Comment: click that link or open an email? if click pass a query string with that. if open an email that link should have some process in db or file i.e pixel code

Comment: It's difficult. You'll could use javascript, but that might not work in an email. The absolute norm is to add a token to the url.

Comment: on clicking that link

Comment: You should never authenticate a user (= give access to secured information) solely on the basis of a link in an email.

Comment: I am not exactly authenticating. I am showing some selected product based on that token on my website. @KIKOSoftware

Comment: @Vikash: Ah you mean: 'identify a user'. Could you explain what your objection is to passing the token in the url?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware : There is no objection, I just don't want to send the lengthy url :P, and Want to know is it possible or not

Comment: Normal people don't look at url's, they don't know what they are. Ask someone to type in an url in the address bar and they type what you say into Google's search engine. Also you don't need to show the URL, it could just be a button with a text.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: I am sending the beautiful button only, but when It will redirect then the lengthy url will open. Anyways thanks for replying :)

Comment: Lot's of browsers don't show the URL by default nowadays. Anyway, the token doesn't have to be very long.

Answer (score 0):

the solution maybe somehow tricky but it works well. at first if you wanna personalize the link you can simply do it but you have to do a 2-way encryption in your code. 
you do not need to send a raw token to the email, but you can encrypt it and then send it but it has to be two way encryption cause you want to understand the token. for this purpose simply create a route for your emails like `('/example/{token}/{user}','Email@userAnalyse')` 
and then in your methods you can decrypt the token part with a password like user id or something like that witch is unique about the user you want to give your information. 
you can also encrypt your user info in the email link and then decrypt it with a plane password and then work with your token. 
this way you can ensure that no one but your app and your authenticated user will not get what is inside the link and will never catch the data inside the web page you want to represent. 
hope this would help you.